# Repeated column in mapping for entity: Hiv_AnswerForEntities column: variant_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have problem with inheritance in ORM.

I use JPA/hibernate. I am getting an error that I do not understand. I have declared once column, but error tell me that I've done this twice. It can be messed with inheritance somehow. 
But I don't know why. Please help

Error I get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: myInsurance.models.liability.hivAndVHProtection.Hiv_AnswerForEntities column: variant_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Entities code:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Answer extends Generic<Answer> {
    @OneToOne public Variant variant;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Answer")
@Table(name="mi__Liability_Part_Hiv_Answer")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Hiv_Answer extends Answer {
    @OneToOne public HivAndVHProtection_Variant variant;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("AnswerForEntities")
public class Hiv_AnswerForEntities extends Hiv_Answer {

    public int proffesionGroup;
    public int personCount;
    public int contributionPerPerson;
    @Transient public int totalContribution;
}
```

And full stack trace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:148) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:102) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
        at play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:35) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:139) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.6]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: myInsurance.models.liability.hivAndVHProtection.Hiv_AnswerForEntities column: variant_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:704) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:479) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass.validate(UnionSubclass.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1283) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1734) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.CR1.jar:4.2.0.CR1]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

--EDIT--

All my `Variant` classes that I use As relation in my `Entities`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Variant extends GenericDictionary<Variant> {}

@Entity
@Table(name="mi__Liability_Part_Hiv_Var")
public class HivAndVHProtection_Variant extends Variant {
    @OneToMany public List<HivAndVHProtection_VariantValue> hivAndVHProtection_VariantValue = new LinkedList<HivAndVHProtection_VariantValue>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mi__Liability_Part_Legal_Var")
public class LegalExpensesInsurance_Variant extends GenericDictionary<LegalExpensesInsurance_Variant> {
    @OneToMany private List<LegalExpensesInsurance_VariantValue> legalExpensesInsurance_VariantValues = new LinkedList<LegalExpensesInsurance_VariantValue>();
}
```

All of this `Variant` like classes extends superclass `Variant`

I've tried also:
    `@OneToOne public Class<? extends Variant> variant;`
but getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on myInsurance.models.liability.hivAndVHProtection.Hiv_Answer.variant references an unknown entity: java.lang.Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Answer` you have

```
@OneToOne public Variant variant;
```

And in `Hiv_Answer` you have

```
@OneToOne public HivAndVHProtection_Variant variant;
```

Join column's name for both of these mappings defaults to `variant_id`, in which case JPA forces you to mark one of them with `insertable = "false", updateable = "false"` because you can't maintain the same field through multiple mappings.

Your options are:

1. Change variable name `variant` to something else in one of these mappings (preferred)
2. Use `@JoinColumn` on at least one mapping to specify a different join column instead of the default one (`variant_id`)

Comment: `Answer` is superclass. It is only for inheritance. The same goes with `Variant` class. They can't have db entry.
 Classes: `Hiv_Answer`,`Hiv_AnswerForEntities`,`HivAndVHProtection_Variant` or `LegalExpensesInsurance_VariantValue` are real entities and does should have db entry. Can You help to correctly write Annotation mapping for this structure?